# R write.csv is creating an empty file

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv, data-cleaning

Some background for my question: This is an R script that a previous research assistant wrote, but he did not provide any guidance to me on using it for myself. After working through an R textbook, I attempted to use the code on my data files.

What this code is supposed to do is load multiple .csv files, delete certain items/columns from them, and then write the new cleaned .csv files to a specified directory.

Currently, the files are being created in the right directory with the right file name, but the .csv files that are being created are empty.

I am currently getting the following error message:

> Warning in
>   fread(input = paste0("data/", str_match(pattern = "CAFAS|PECFAS",:  Starting data input on line 2 and discarding line 1 because it has too few or too many items to be column names or data: (variable names).

This is my code:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

# create a function to delete unnecessary variables from a CAFAS or PECFAS 
data set and save the reduced copy

del.items <- function(file){  
  data <- fread(input = paste0("data/", str_match(pattern = "CAFAS|PECFAS", 
string = file) %>% tolower, "/raw/", file), sep = ",", header = TRUE, 
na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip = 0, colClasses = 
"character", data.table = FALSE)

   data <- data[-grep(pattern = "^(CA|PEC)FAS_E[0-9]+(TR?(Initial|[0-
 9]+|Exit)|SP[a-z])_(G|S|Item)[0-9]+$", x = names(data))]

  write.csv(data, file = paste0("data/", str_match(pattern = "CAFAS|PECFAS", 
string = file) %>% tolower, "/items-del/", sub(pattern = "ExportData_", x = 
file, replacement = "")) %>% tolower, row.names = FALSE)
}

# delete items from all cafas data sets

cafas.files <- list.files("data/cafas/raw", pattern = ".csv")

for (file in cafas.files){
  del.items(file)
}

# delete items from all pecfas data sets

pecfas.files <- list.files("data/pecfas/raw", pattern = ".csv")

for (file in pecfas.files){
  del.items(file)
}
```

Comment: That warning message may or may not be a problem, depending on the input csv. 
It's hard to tell what's wrong without a small sample of the data

Comment: Spinodal: I can't upload any of my data files, but I can do my best to describe them to you. Is there any way to send one to you? These files are large .csv files that contain participant data from an evaluation scale. In the unclean files (the input .csv files), there are tens of thousands of column variables. Each .csv file also has hundreds of participant rows. The purpose of this script is to completely delete the unnecessary columns, which are selected through the -grep function above.

Comment: Are you sure R is an appropriate tool for this? It sounds to me like AWK or something like that would do the job better.

Comment: I mean, that's just a warning message, not an error message. And it's really about the first three lines of your input file. You should at least show us the first three lines of a file that's issuing the warning to see if it makes sense or not. The files are empty probably because of a bad subsetting command. But that would depend entirely on seeing what's actually in the file and describing in words exactly what you want to subset to see if the code is doing the right thing.